# C++/CLI wrapper around a C library

Tags: c, wrapper, c++-cli

I have a C library written by a third-party company. It calculates photo positions on a book page, position of a photo inside an area (which part of the photo to crop), it fills a book with random photos...
I have created a .Net wrapper around the C library. I'm very new to C++ so I don't know the conventions (naming, ordering...).

The idea for the .Net wrapper is to create a "usable" library, not to bind the methods one-to-one. For instance, from a C# perspective, it seems stupid to send the size of an array to a method.
I also want to use "real" data types, for instance a Unix timestamp used by the C library is transformed to and from a `DateTime` for .Net use.

The C library (which I can't really modify) is composed of this:

> ```
> /**
>  * A frame is defined by four measures
>  *
>  *     +-----------------------------+
>  *     |        ^             ^      |
>  *     |        |top          |      |
>  *     |        V             |      |
>  *     |<------>+------------+|      |
>  *     |  left  |            ||bottom|
>  *     |        +------------+V      |
>  *     |<-------------------->       |
>  *     |          right              |
>  *     +-----------------------------+
>  */
> typedef struct {
>   int left;
>   int top;
>   int right;
>   int bottom;
> } frame_t;
>
> /**
>  * An image
>  */
> typedef struct {
>   /* IN */
>   int     width;     // The width of the original file (used by page and book functions)
>   int     height;    // The height of the original file (page and book)
>   int     group;     // Images from different groups should not be put on the same page (book only)
>   int     nb_hints;  // The number of hints
>   frame_t *hints;    // Hints are important areas that should not be cropped
>
>   /* OUT */
>   frame_t view;      // The viewport, to crop the original image (set by page and book functions)
>   frame_t dest;      // The destination, to place the cropped image (page and book)
>   int     page;      // The page number of a book (book only)
> } image_t;
>
> /**
>  * Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the
>  * aspect ratio of the original image. If necessary, crop the image in the
>  * larger dimension. Also, try to preserve in the image the faces and features
>  * (= the hints).
>  *
>  * @param image The image to resize
>  * @param width The width of the resized image
>  * @param height The height of the resized image
>  * @return the score (higher is better)
>  */
> int resize_to_fill(image_t *image, int width, int height);
>
> /**
>  * Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the
>  * aspect ratio of the original image. The image may be shorter or narrower
>  * than specified in the smaller dimension but will not be larger than the
>  * specified values.
>  *
>  * @param image The image to resize
>  * @param width The width of the resized image
>  * @param height The height of the resized image
>  * @return the score (higher is better)
>  */
> int resize_to_fit(image_t *image, int width, int height);
>
> /**
>  * Parameters for packing images on a page
>  */
> typedef struct {
>   int page_width;   // The width of the page
>   int page_height;  // The height of the page
>   int margin;       // The margin thickness
>   int nb_run;       // The number of tries for each algorithm
> } parameters_t;
>
> /**
>  * Pack the images on the page. It fills the position, offset and crop of the
>  * images in a pleasant way.
>  *
>  * @param images The images to pack
>  * @param nb_images The number of images
>  * @param params The parameters (size of the page and margin)
>  * @return the score of the best allocation found
>  */
> int pack(image_t *images, int nb_images, parameters_t params);
>
> /**
>  * Select an image and position it on a cover.
>  *
>  * @param images The images to pack
>  * @param nb_images The number of images
>  * @param params The parameters (size of the page and margin)
>  * @return the index of the selected image
>  */
> int cover(image_t *images, int nb_images, parameters_t params);
>
> /**
>  * Parameters for packing images in a book
>  */
> typedef struct {
>   int          min;      // The minimum number of images per page
>   int          max;      // The maximum number of images per page
>   int          nb_pages; // The number of pages
>   int          nb_books; // The number of tries for generating a book
>   parameters_t page;     // The parameters for packing images on each page
> } book_parameters_t;
>
> /**
>  * Pack the images in a book.
>  *
>  * @param images The images to pack
>  * @param nb_images The number of images
>  * @param params The parameters (size of the page and margin)
>  * @return the score of the best allocation found
>  */
> int pack_book(image_t *images, int nb_images, book_parameters_t params);
>
> /**
>  * The time when a photo was taken, to clusterize photos in groups.
>  * When this time is not known, put 0 in timestamp.
>  */
> typedef struct {
>   /* IN */
>   int timestamp;  // When the photo was taken
>
>   /* OUT */
>   int group;      // The identifier of the group for this photo
> } photo_timestamp_t;
>
> /**
>  * Create groups of photos.
>  * Images are expected to be sorted by timestamp.
>  *
>  * @param images The images to group
>  * @param nb_images The number of images
>  * @return the number of groups
>  */
> int clusterize(photo_timestamp_t *images, int nb_images);
> ```

And the C++/CLI library this around it. The comments are C#-style to provide intellisense in the calling project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Position of an image on a page
/// </summary>
public ref class Frame {
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Position of the left side of the frame
    /// </summary>
    int Left;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position of the right top side of the frame
    /// </summary>
    int Top;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position of the right side of the frame relative to the left of the page
    /// </summary>
    int Right;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position of the bottom side of the frame relative to the top of the page
    /// </summary>
    int Bottom;

    /// <summary>
    /// Width of the frame
    /// </summary>
    property int Width {
        int get() {
            return (Right - Left);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Height of the frame
    /// </summary>
    property int Height {
        int get() {
            return (Bottom - Top);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Frame class
    /// </summary>
    Frame() {
        Top = 0;
        Left = 0;
        Bottom = 0;
        Right = 0;
    }

internal:
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the managed frame to a native structure
    /// </summary>
    frame_t ToNative() {
        frame_t f;
        f.left = Left;
        f.top = Top;
        f.right = Right;
        f.bottom = Bottom;
        return f;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a managed frame from a native structure
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// see: stackoverflow.com/a/3158445/6776
    /// </remarks>
    Frame(const frame_t &f) {
        Left = f.left;
        Top = f.top;
        Right = f.right;
        Bottom = f.bottom;
    }
};

/// <summary>
/// Describes an image
/// </summary>
public ref class Image {
private:
    void init(int nb_hints) {
        this->view = gcnew Frame();
        this->dest = gcnew Frame();
        this->page = 0;
        this->Hints = gcnew array<Frame^>(nb_hints);
    }

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// The width of the original file
    /// </summary>
    int Width;

    /// <summary>
    /// The height of the original file
    /// </summary>
    int Height;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the group of the image
    /// </summary>
    property int Group {
        int get() {
            return group;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of important areas that should not be cropped
    /// </summary>
    array<Frame^>^ Hints;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the page number of the image
    /// </summary>
    property int Page {
        int get() {
            return this->page;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the viewport (to crop the image)
    /// </summary>
    property Frame^ View {
        Frame^ get() {
            return this->view;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the destination (to place the image on the page)
    /// </summary>
    property Frame^ Dest {
        Frame^ get() {
            return this->dest;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Image class
    /// </summary>
    Image(int nb_hints) {
        this->init(nb_hints);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Image class
    /// </summary>
    Image() {
        this->init(0);
    }

internal:
    /// <summary>
    /// The viewport (to crop the image)
    /// </summary>
    Frame^ view;

    /// <summary>
    /// The destination (to place the image on the page)
    /// </summary>
    Frame^ dest;

    /// <summary>
    /// The page number
    /// </summary>
    int page;

    /// <summary>
    /// The group of the image
    /// </summary>
    int group;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Image class
    /// </summary>
    Image(image_t native) {
        this->Width = native.width;
        this->Height = native.height;

        this->Hints = gcnew array<Frame^>(native.nb_hints);
        for (int i = 0; i < native.nb_hints; i++)
        {
            this->Hints[i] = gcnew Frame(native.hints[i]);
        }

        this->group = native.group;
        this->page = native.page;
        this->dest = gcnew Frame(native.dest);
        this->view = gcnew Frame(native.view);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the managed image to a native structure
    /// </summary>
    image_t ToNative() {
        image_t i;
        i.width = this->Width;
        i.height = this->Height;
        i.group = this->Group;

        // hints
        i.nb_hints = this->Hints->Length;
        i.hints = new frame_t[this->Hints->Length];
        for (int nb = 0; nb < this->Hints->Length; nb++)
        {
            i.hints[nb] = this->Hints[nb]->ToNative();
        }

        // output values
        i.page = this->Page;
        i.view = this->View->ToNative();
        i.dest = this->Dest->ToNative();

        return i;
    }
};

/// <summary>
/// Parameters for packing images on a page
/// </summary>
public ref class Parameters {
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// The width of the page
    /// </summary>
    int PageWidth;

    /// <summary>
    /// The height of the page
    /// </summary>
    int PageHeight;

    /// <summary>
    /// The margin between images
    /// </summary>
    int Margin;

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of tries for each algorithm (generally in the hundreds)
    /// </summary>
    int NbRun;

internal:
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the managed parameter to a native structure
    /// </summary>
    parameters_t ToNative() {
        parameters_t p;
        p.page_width = this->PageWidth;
        p.page_height = this->PageHeight;
        p.margin = this->Margin;
        p.nb_run = this->NbRun;
        return p;
    }
};

/// <summary>
/// Parameters for packing images in a book
/// </summary>
public ref class BookParameters {
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// The minimum number of images per page
    /// </summary>
    int MinPerPage;

    /// <summary>
    /// The maximum number of images per page
    /// </summary>
    int MaxPerPage;

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of pages
    /// </summary>
    int NbPages;

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of "tentative" books generated (generally several thousands)
    /// </summary>
    int NbRun;

    /// <summary>
    /// The parameters for each page
    /// </summary>
    Parameters^ PageParam;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the BookParameters class
    /// </summary>
    BookParameters(Parameters^ parameters) {
        this->PageParam = parameters;
    }

internal:
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the managed parameter to a native structure
    /// </summary>
    book_parameters_t ToNative() {
        book_parameters_t p;
        p.max = this->MaxPerPage;
        p.min = this->MinPerPage;
        p.nb_pages = this->NbPages;
        p.nb_books = this->NbRun;
        p.page = this->PageParam->ToNative();
        return p;
    }
};

/// <summary>
/// The time when a photo was taken, to clusterize photos in groups.
/// When this time is not known, put 0 in timestamp
/// </summary>
public ref class PhotoTimestamp {
public:
    /// <summary>
    /// When the photo was taken
    /// </summary>
    System::DateTime^ Timestamp;

    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier of the group for this photo
    /// </summary>
    property int Group {
        int get() {
            return this->group;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the PhotoTimestamp class
    /// </summary>
    PhotoTimestamp()
    {
        this->group = 0;
    }

internal:
    /// <summary>
    /// The calculated group of the image
    /// </summary>
    int group;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the PhotoTimestamp class
    /// </summary>
    PhotoTimestamp(photo_timestamp_t t) {
        this->group = t.group;

        System::DateTime^ timestamp = gcnew DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System::DateTimeKind::Utc);
        timestamp = timestamp->AddSeconds(t.timestamp).ToLocalTime();
        this->Timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the managed timestamp to a native structure
    /// </summary>
    photo_timestamp_t ToNative() {
        photo_timestamp_t t;
        t.group = this->Group;

        // convert the date to a UNIX timestamp
        t.timestamp = this->Timestamp->ToUniversalTime().Subtract(System::DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

        return t;
    }
};

/// <summary>
/// Packing of the images
/// </summary>
public ref class Packer {
private:
    /// <summary>
    /// The images list
    /// </summary>
    array<Image^>^ images;

    /// <summary>
    /// The packing parameters
    /// </summary>
    Parameters^ params;

    /// <summary>
    /// References the native images structures
    /// </summary>
    image_t *nativeImages;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the values from the native images and stores them to the managed ones
    /// </summary>
    void NativeToManagedImages() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->images->Length; i++) {
            images[i]->view = gcnew Frame(this->nativeImages[i].view);
            images[i]->dest = gcnew Frame(this->nativeImages[i].dest);
            images[i]->page = this->nativeImages[i].page;
            images[i]->group = this->nativeImages[i].group;
        }
    }

public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Packer class
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="images">The images to pack</param>
    /// <param name="params">The parameters for the packing</param>
    Packer(array< Image^ >^ %images, Parameters^ params) {
        srand(time(NULL));

        this->images = images;
        this->params = params;

        // create a native array of image_t to send to the native library
        this->nativeImages = new image_t[this->images->Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->images->Length; i++) {
            this->nativeImages[i] = this->images[i]->ToNative();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deallocates the class and frees up memory
    /// </summary>
    ~Packer() {
        delete[] this->nativeImages;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resizes an image to fill within the specified dimensions
    /// while retaining the aspect ratio of the original. If necessary,
    /// crop the image in the larger dimension.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image to resize</param>
    /// <param name="width">The width of the destination area</param>
    /// <param name="height">The height of the destination area</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The score of the resize
    /// </returns>
    static int ResizeToFill(Image^ %image, int width, int height) {
        image_t native = image->ToNative();

        int result = resize_to_fill(&native, width, height);

        image = gcnew Image(native);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resizes the image to fit within the specified dimensions
    /// while retaining the aspect ration of the original. The image
    /// may be shorter or narrower than specified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image to resize</param>
    /// <param name="width">The width of the destination area</param>
    /// <param name="height">The height of the destination area</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The score of the resize
    /// </returns>
    static int ResizeToFit(Image^ %image, int width, int height) {
        image_t native = image->ToNative();

        int result = resize_to_fit(&native, width, height);

        image = gcnew Image(native);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates groups of photos from their timestamps.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Images are expected to be sorted by timestamp.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="images">The images infos to clusterize</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The number of groups
    /// </returns>
    static int Clusterize(array<PhotoTimestamp^>^ %images) {
        photo_timestamp_t *timestamps = new photo_timestamp_t[images->Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < images->Length; i++) {
            timestamps[i] = images[i]->ToNative();
        }

        int result = clusterize(timestamps, images->Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < images->Length; i++)
        {
            images[i] = gcnew PhotoTimestamp(timestamps[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Selects an image to position on a cover
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The index of the selected image
    /// </returns>
    int Cover() {
        int result = cover(nativeImages, this->images->Length, params->ToNative());

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Packs the images on the sheet
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The score of the best allocation found
    /// </returns>
    int Pack() {
        int result = pack(this->nativeImages, this->images->Length, this->params->ToNative());

        this->NativeToManagedImages();

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Packs the images in a book
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bookParameters">The parameters for the book packing</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The score of the best allocation found
    /// </returns>
    int PackBook(BookParameters^ bookParameters) {
        int result = pack_book(this->nativeImages, this->images->Length, bookParameters->ToNative());

        this->NativeToManagedImages();

        return result;
    }
};
```

I am specifically concerned about several things.

First, could there be a better way to convert native to and from managed? I feel this way is not very memory efficient (lots of copying data around), but I fear using more efficient methods (like using `pin_ptr`) will add complexity to the code (and memory corruption risks) for a negligible performance gain. The app already takes several hundred Mbs and several seconds/minutes to call this method so I don't care about shaving a few milliseconds if it means refactoring everything.

While copying this code, I have noticed that the native-to-managed constructors `Frame(const frame_t &f)` and `Image(image_t native)` do not follow the same "signature style" (I have written them months apart). Is there a significant difference (apart from pointer vs value), and potential problem that could arise ?

Is there a risk somewhere (some kind of red flag or anti-pattern, perhaps) for potential memory leak or corruption ?
I was pointed [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387812/do-i-need-to-delete-unmanaged-objects-in-c-cli) to the risk in the `ResizeToFit` wrapper method that the `image_t` instance I create may be "bound" in some way to the `Image` instance, because the `image_t` structure has a pointer (`* hints`) so it creates a shallow copy when passing it to the `Image(image_t native)` constructor. Have I understood correctly?

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: I don't get what this has to do with C++ at all. You're showing C and C# code.

Comment: This is not C#. It's C++/CLI. Admittedly it's a little different from standard C++, but I thought not enough that C++ reviewers wouldn't have anything to say. It's just written in C# style (comments style, CamelCase...).

Comment: but the Internal: keyword is not in C++ but exists in C#.  That's what's confusing me. Shouldn't it be "protected" or "public private:" instead of "internal:"?

Comment: Internal makes the member visible to all objects inside the library, so the `ToNative` methods can be called by other classes of the project, but not from the "calling" project.

Comment: I have removed the C++ tag because none of the code is in C++, and the question itself has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, why are you using C++/CLI? The C API looks relatively simple, you should be able to write the wrapper in C# using PInvoke, with the advantage that you won't have to write all that copying code.

---

> ```
> int Left;
> ```

Public fields are considered bad practice in .Net. Instead, you can use *shorthand property syntax*:

```
property int Left;
```

---

> ```
> Frame() {
>     Top = 0;
>     Left = 0;
>     Bottom = 0;
>     Right = 0;
> }
> ```

All fields of managed types are automatically initialized to the default value, so I think this is unnecessary code.

---

> ```
> Image(int nb_hints) {
>     this->init(nb_hints);
> }
>
> Image() {
>     this->init(0);
> }
> ```

You can use delegating constructor for this:

```
Image(int nb_hints) {
    // actual initialization code here
}

Image() : Image(0) {
}
```

---

Consider changing the type of `Hints` to something like `List<Frame^>^` or  `IList^. That way, working with it will be easier.

---

> ```
> System::DateTime^ Timestamp;
> ```

`DateTime` is a structure (`value class` in C++/CLI, `struct` in C#), so there is no need to use a handle here.

---

> ```
> array< Image^ >^ %images
> ```

I don't see any reason why this should be a tracking reference.

---

> ```
> Packer(array< Image^ >^ %images, Parameters^ params) {
>     srand(time(NULL));
>
>     this->images = images;
>     this->params = params;
>
>     // create a native array of image_t to send to the native library
>     this->nativeImages = new image_t[this->images->Length];
>     for (int i = 0; i < this->images->Length; i++) {
>         this->nativeImages[i] = this->images[i]->ToNative();
>     }
> }
>
> ~Packer() {
>     delete[] this->nativeImages;
> }
> ```

Since `Image::ToNative()` allocates unmanaged memory using `new` and you're never deallocating it, this is going to cause a memory leak. I think the right solution here is to iterate through `nativeImages` in `~Packer` and `delete[]` their `hints` there.

---

If I understand [how destructors and finalizers work in C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d#BKMK_Destructors_and_finalizers) correctly, then cleanup of unmanaged resources (like your arrays) should be done in the finalizer, which should then also be called from the destructor:

```
~Packer() {
    this->!Packer();
}

!Packer() {
    delete[] this->nativeImages;
}
```

This way, the unmanaged memory is (eventually) released even if you forgot to call the destructor (by using `delete` or stack semantics in C++/CLI and `Dispose()` or `using` in C#).

Comment: Thanks! A few remarks: constructor chaining (delegating) is not supported in C++/CLI. I couldn't make the code work without the handle to the timestamp. The `%images` tracking reference is because the values are modified in the C function. Thanks for the memory management tips!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> static int ResizeToFill(Image^ %image, int width, int height) {
>     image_t native = image->ToNative();
>
>     int result = resize_to_fill(&native, width, height);
>
>     image = gcnew Image(native);
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```

This method (and the others) does not really change the image but it creates a new one which is not obvious and the user of this method would think he does not need to dispose the old image. I suggest adding another `[Out]` parameter for the result while changing the first parameter from `%` (ref) to normal by-ref parameter.

```
static int ResizeToFill(Image^ image, int width, int height, [Out] Image^ %result)
{
    image_t native = image->ToNative();

    int score = resize_to_fill(&native, width, height);

    result = gcnew Image(native);

    return score;
}
```